# Issues creating a widget with repeated functionality in Javascript

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

Have a controller class setup as a widget.  Labeled here as "buttonController".  I'm trying to call and instantiate an instance of the controller widget per each button.  Everything seemingly works, except that the loop apparently is not calling 3 instances, but resetting the same widget with the last bit of data.  Meaning the options are only being set as the last object in buttons.  Feel either you can not call the widget more than once, or my loop is not doing what I expect.  Any thoughts?

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'buttonController',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/jquery.parsequery'
], function ($, _, ButtonController) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.supplementalbuttons', {
        options: {
            spConfig: {},
            superSelector: '.supplemental-super-attribute-select',
            selectSimpleProduct: '[name="selected_configurable_option"]',
            state: {},
            containerSelector: '#supplemental-configurable',
            buttonSelector: '',
            formSelector: '#supplemental-configurable form',
            skuSelector: '.supplemental-sku',
            action: '',
            buttons: {}
       },

       /**
        * Creates widget
        * @private
        */
       _create: function () {
           // Initial setting of various option values
           this._initialize();

           $(this.element).trigger('supplementalbuttons.initialized');
       },

        /**
         * @private
         */
        _initialize: function () {
            var options = this.options;
            var element = this.element;
            var buttons = options.buttons;
            $.each(buttons, function(key, value){
              var buttonController = new ButtonController;
              var buttonSelector = "button#" + key + "-" + value.sku;
              buttonController.element = element;
              buttonController.options = options;
              buttonController.options.spConfig = value.spConfig;
              buttonController.options.action = value.action;
              buttonController.options.buttonSelector = buttonSelector;
              buttonController._create();
            });
        }


    });

    return $.mage.supplementalbuttons;
});
```